# Refresh rate stuck at 144Hz nvidia optimus Kubuntu Prime intel graphics mode

Tags: xorg, display, xrandr, plasma, nvidia-prime

I am trying to change my refresh rate to 60 Hz from 144 Hz on my Razer blade 15 mercury running Kubuntu 20.04. I have an RTX 2060 and it uses Nvidia Optimus. I have the PRIME setting to Intel because I want to get better battery life and plan on enabling the discrete GPU when I need it for computing tasks. I have tried reinstalling all the drivers and even tried installing regular Ubuntu but the refresh rate will not change to 60 Hz even if I use xrandr. When I use it acts as it applies, it even changes the resolution but does not change the refresh rate. It is stuck at 144 Hz.

The main reason I want to do this is the battery drains a lot faster on Kubuntu and ubuntu than when running windows. I had a Powershell script on windows that would change the refresh rate to 60 when on battery. I have found is that the refresh rate will not change to 60 even though it should.

I used the following command and it does nothing, it doesn't even flicker the display. I ran glxgears after to see if it actually applied and the refresh rate doesn't apply. I can also tell it is running faster than 60 Hz because it is too smooth to be at 60.
I ran the following:

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 60
```

I had no output so I assumed it applied. I then ran `xrandr` and it looks like it is applied but I can tell it didn't actually.

```
$xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080    144.00 +  60.01    59.97    59.96    60.00*   59.93  
   1680x1050     84.94    74.89    69.88    59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     85.00    74.76    70.00    59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     85.02    75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      85.00    60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864     100.00    85.06    85.00    75.00    75.00    70.00    60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      85.00    75.05    60.04    85.00    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   1024x768i     86.96  
   960x720       85.00    75.00    60.00  
   928x696       75.00    60.05  
   896x672       75.05    60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       85.00    75.00    70.00    65.00    60.00    85.14    72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       85.02    74.96    69.88    60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       85.08    74.76    70.06    59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       85.02    75.02    60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       85.09    60.00    85.01    72.81    75.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   720x400       85.04  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98    85.08  
   576x432      100.11    85.15    85.09    75.00    75.00    70.00    60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   640x350       85.08  
   512x384       85.00    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   512x384i      87.06  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   416x312       74.66  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       85.27    72.19    75.12    60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       85.18    72.81    75.00    60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   360x200       85.04  
   320x200       85.27  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
   320x175       85.27  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

When I run `glxgears` it shows

```
Running synchronized to the vertical refresh.  The framerate should be
approximately the same as the monitor refresh rate.
690 frames in 5.0 seconds = 137.892 FPS
688 frames in 5.0 seconds = 137.444 FPS
687 frames in 5.0 seconds = 137.389 FPS
X connection to :0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
```

I have tried enabling the Nvidia card and changing it and it seems to respond to refresh rate changes but it disables vsync so it refreshes at 60 but it renders thousands of frames per second so it kinda defeats the point because the secondary GPU is enabled.

I would like to figure out how to reduce the refresh rate when running on integrated graphics if it is at all possible. I am a Linux noob so I am sorry if this is an easy fix. I am trying to leave Windows behind but I can't if my battery only lasts 30% of what it does on Windows.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If logs are needed please let me know. As mentioned above, I am new to Linux and Kubuntu so I may need pretty straightforward instruction.

I searched for a while on similar issues and haven't found anything that has worked yet. Most of them just say to use `xrandr` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? I can't set a higher refresh rate that the laptop monitor is capable of.

Comment: I'm also stuck at 144hz, but I can't even switch to anything other than the nvidia driver, and xrandr doesn't show any option other than 144hz for my display. :/ G5 5590 with 2070mq for me, on pop os 20.10.